# Hypercohomology - now replaced by derived functors?

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-functors

On the Wikipedia article for hypercohomology I find the following sentence.

> Hyperhomology is no longer used much: since about 1970 it has been
>   largely replaced by the roughly equivalent concept of a derived
>   functor between derived categories.

Unfortunately, they give no reference. Is there a good article or book that explains the new definition using derived functors between derived categories and the equivalence between the two concepts?

Possibly this is a stupid question and the equivalence follows easily from the relevant definitions. I just started reading about hypercohomology and don't know anything about derived categories. If this is the case, I'd also like to know. Even a thumbnail sketch of what's going on would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The sentence at the end of the "Definition" section of the article gives the answer...

Comment: I was looking for a more introductory source. The formulation in terms of abelian categories is not the one I've seen.

Comment: The two concepts are not equivalent. Hypercohomology is the homology of the derived functor. The idea that the former has been replaced by the latter can only be help by someone who has never computed neither...

Comment: If you know nothing about derived categories, then a good plan would be for you to read about them and then come back, really! There are very good write ups which you can find online (Bernhard Keller has a few, for example) It is more or less impossible to talk about derived functors if one does not mknow about derived categories. If you plan to do anything related to homological algebra theses days, you will need to do this anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Once you understand the construction of a derived category and what the derived pushforward is all about, then the answer is easy: If you have a complex in $C^\bullet \in D(X)$ and a map $p:X \to pt$, then $\mathbb{H}^k(X,C^\bullet) = \mathbf{R}^kp_*(C^\bullet) = H^k(\mathbf{R}p_*(C^\bullet))$. Note that I make no reference to which derived category you are looking at since this is irrelevant; it holds true for coherent sheaves, local systems, constructible complexes, and so forth.

Comment: are $f$ and $p$ meant to be the same here?

Comment: @Tim Thanks, it's fixed